# Remove ambiguity in function call on implicitly converted smart pointer

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, implicit-conversion, ambiguous

I'm reading item 28 on smart pointers of Scott Meyers's *More Effective C++* and have the following question.

A complete demonstration can be found at http://ideone.com/aKq6C0 .

A derived class pointer can be converted implicitly to a base class pointer:

```
class Base {};
class Derived : public Base {};
void foo(Base* b) { cout << "foo called on Base pointer" << endl;}
Derived *d = new Derived();
foo(d); //No problem
```

But such implicit conversion cannot happen for smart pointers, i.e. `SmartPtr<Derived>` cannot be implicitly converted to `SmartPtr<Base>`. So we use a member template for such conversions:

```
template<typename T>
class SmartPtr {
public:
  //constructors, operator->, etc

  //member template for type conversion
  template<NewType>
  operator SmartPtr<NewType> () {
    return SmartPtr<NewType>(pointee);
  }
private:
  T* pointee;//the raw pointer
};
```

This can almost work, but it can cause ambiguity:

```
class Remote {};
class Base : public Remote {};
class Derived : public Base {};
void foo(const SmartPtr<Remote>& p) { cout << "remote" << endl;}
void foo(const SmartPtr<Base>& p) { cout << "base" << endl;}

SmartPtr<Derived> d(new Derived());
foo(d);//compile error: ambiguity
```

In this example, the compiler does not know whether it should convert `d` to `SmartPtr<Base>` or `SmartPtr<Remote>`, although for a raw pointer `Base` is apparently superior. The book says

> The best we can do is to use member templates to generate conversion functions, then use casts in those cases where ambiguity results.

But how exactly do we apply cast here? `foo(static_cast<SmartPtr<Base>>(d))` does not compile either. From the error message I can tell that the error comes from the use of non-const reference in the copy-constructor of `SmartPtr`. I'm wondering what's the correct way to make the function call.

Comment: Not answer qustion, but `return SmartPtr<NewType>(pointee);` seems not right, you need something like `std::week_ptr` to do this

Comment: You should look at the standard smart pointers, and how they provide conversion (e.g.) from `std::shared_ptr<Derived>` to `std::shared_ptr<Base>` when (and only when) `Derived*` is convertible to `Base*`.

Comment: Your cast is correct, what is missing is code for your copy constructors. If you have one that takes non-const ref - you would get the error you mentioned, if you can just change ref to being const in copy ctor and code would compile (tested)

Answer (score 0):

```
//constructors
```

This is the most important part that you have omitted :)

Your cast is correct as such, it all depends on set of constructors you have. If you have one that takes non-const ref - you would get the error you mentioned, if you can just change ref to being const in copy ctor and code would compile.

It may be not very obvious, but when you call

```
return SmartPtr<NewType>(pointee);
```

you are constructing new `SmartPtr<NewType>` that have to accept `T*`, and `NewType` and `T` are different types. Most likely you only have ctor that accepts raw pointer of same type (i.e. `T*` for `SmartPtr<T>` and `X*` for `SmartPtr<X>`) so compiler is looking for another [converting ctor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor) to create your new SmartPtr and finds your copy ctor, but it can't bind new value to non const ref

---

Edit:

IF you are using c++11 adding move ctor would also solve your problem as it would be able to bind to rvalue

```
SmartPtr( SmartPtr<T>&& other): pointee(other.pointee) { other.pointee = nullptr; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Oleg. You can check the complete definition of `SmartPtr` in the ideone page I provided above http://ideone.com/aKq6C0 . I took it directly from the book, and the behavior of `SmartPtr` basically decides that it has to take a non-const reference in its copy constructor (kind of like the deprecated `auto_ptr`).

Comment: are you using c++11 ? you can solve your problem also by adding move ctor?     `SmartPtr( SmartPtr<T>&&)` ..